# How to make a form in flutter so that it can be Reusable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

I have one line of code to create a form to add a product on flutter. and I made very long code for the label and text field. Can you explain the method to minimize the lines of code and make the labels and text fields reusable?

Comment: can you provide any snippet code that what you had try?